# C#: How to switch one property on when another property turns off on the map editor in real time?

Tags: c#, click, propertygrid

I am trying to make a C# code to turn on one property item, "property 2," when "property 1" is off on the property grid view in real time, respectively. In the graph, I put the word on or off in the second column, but it is a click button. The default is true (the blue-clicked box). The code I made only works when I save the changes and open the property grid view. But I would like to see the changes in real time. So if I click "property 1", "property 2" is automatically turned off, and vice versa.

I have searched several posts, but without samples, it is hard to understand them. Thank you.

| property 1 | on |
| --- | --- |
| property 2 | off |

===============================================================
I have a similar setting as in the attached figure. In the figure, if "Enabled" is a bool and clicked, I'd like to have "Selected" unclicked in real time automatically, and vice versa.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw6J4.jpg)

Comment: Whic property grid are you talking about? This one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid ?

Comment: Have you tried implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: Simon, I am a C# novice. To your question, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know understand your problems.
But you can use following code in your class :

```
public bool State{get;set;}
public string Property1=>State?"on":"";
public string Property2=>State?"":"off";
```

When set **State** property , change **Property1** and **Property2**.